Got an error playing video with Pod Player Flutter
I'm using a pod_player package to play videos, but I got the following exception:
===== VIMEO API ERROR: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast ==========
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
#0      PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:76:9)
#1      PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized[(package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:82:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:82:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PodPlayerController.initialise (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:61:5)

Error screen:
error screen
Tried downgrading the version but not working.

After upgrading the version to pod_player: ^0.2.2, the issue was resolved, remember you might have to upgrade your flutter version as well
